# Pressing Home key on commented line places caret after double slash

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

In my Eclipse IDE, a "Smart Caret Positioning" feature is turned on. Pressing Home key on a line that is indented with whitespace will swap the caret between two positions:

1. After indentation whitespace, before the first non-whitespace character
2. Before indentation whitespace, at the true beginning of the line

```
        package stack.overflow;
^2      ^1
```

This is **correct and expected**.

However, when the lines start with a double slash (a line comment), the behavior is different. The Home key swaps the caret between these two:

1. After indentation whitespace and double slash (It is specifically ignoring first two slashes. Additional slashes are not ignored.)
2. Before indentation whitespace, at the true beginning of the line

```
        //package stack.overflow;
^2        ^1
```

How can I stop Eclipse from ignoring the double slash on a line comment? I should get one of the following behaviors:

```
        //package stack.overflow;
^2      ^1
```

```
        //package stack.overflow;
^3      ^2^1
```

**Note:** I know I can turn off the "Smart Caret Positioning" feature but I want to keep it turned on and use it.

Comment: This sounds more like a bug report than a Stack Overflow question

Comment: Yeah I suppose it is, but wanted to know if anyone managed to find a solution (a setting or plugin). I'll check Eclipse bug tracker if it was reported. Usually bugs like this can go unnoticed for years there!